# Unable to locate the element in selenium

Tags: selenium

I am trying to identify the element after login into https://www.box.com application however it throws an error '**Element is not visible**'

**Steps** :

1) Login to https://www.box.com application.
2) Create New folder  'test' from 'New' button.
3) Verify folder is created successfully
4) Try to locate that element with xpath and css but it throws an error element is not visible

The same problem occurs with when I create a new file and tried to identify it. 
Can anybody help me.

Comment: do you have any test credentials for login ?

Comment: at what point you are getting this exception?

Comment: Code trials please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this code. When I was learning automation I had automated Box.com

**Code**  :

```
public void createFolder(String folderName) throws InterruptedException{
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfAllElementsLocatedBy(By.cssSelector("a[class=btn]>span[class=text]")));
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("a[class=btn]>span[class=text]")).click();
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.id("menu-newdropdown")));
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("button[data-type='new-folder']")).click();
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.className("popup-contents")));
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.name("folderName")));
driver.findElement(By.name("folderName")).sendKeys(folderName);
driver.findElement(By.name("folderName")).sendKeys(Keys.RETURN);
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//span[text()='Folder was created successfully.']")));
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.invisibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//span[text()='Folder was created successfully.']")));
}
```

After that you can write the assertion for folder creation.

**Update** :

```
public boolean iSFolderExists(String firstFolderName) throws InterruptedException{
        Thread.sleep(3000);
        List<WebElement> allFolderssName = driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("ol[class*=list-view] a[class=item-name-link]"));
        for(int i =0 ; i<allFolderssName.size() ; i++){                     
                WebElement folderNames = allFolderssName.get(i);
                String a = folderNames.getText();
                String alowerCase = a.toLowerCase();
                String aupperCase = a.toUpperCase();
                if(a.equals(firstFolderName) || alowerCase.equals(firstFolderName) || aupperCase.equals(firstFolderName)){
                    return true;
                }
        }
        return false;
    }
```

Comment: Hi Cruisepandey.. thank you for the response.. actually this code is to create the folder in box account and i am getting the error while identify the already created folder  i have tried the xpath  By.xpath("//*[text()='folder1']") when i have created folder1 in box account

Comment: You can refer the Updated answer under update , This is how I had looked for folder existence.

Comment: You can accept the answer , by clicking on check mark just under the downvote button. So this question would be closed and I would get my reward also. Thanks in advance.